# Convert Cipher Input Stream to Byte array?

Tags: android, encryption, inputstream

Simply, I have a `CipherInputStream` and I want to convert it to a byte array. Other posts didn't help. How to achive this?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("dataPath/data");
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("password".getBytes(), "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
```

So how to retrieve a byte array from `cis`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CipherInputStream` is an implementation of a standard `InputStream`, therefore you can just read it into a byte array using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for example:

```
CipherInputStream cis = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int len;
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while ((len = cis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
baos.flush();
byte[] cipherByteArray = baos.toByteArray(); // get the byte array
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked. Does it make sense to assign say 256 instead of 4096 to the array? Because it won't be that large though i don't know the exact size.

Comment: @solo 4096 is just the buffer size. If you know that the data will usually be smaller than 256 bytes, you may as well use 256.